# mysql_field_type equivalent in sqlsrv

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sqlsrv

Working on converting my code from mysql to sqlsrv. Wondering what the equivalent  for   `mysql_field_type`, hopefully someone knows of a page where I can see more mysql and sql equivalent functions. Cant either find for these two:

```
mysql_field_name

mysql_fetch_row
```

Answer (score 2):

These are PHP functions for MySQL. 
Similarly, there are functions for MS SQL Server too.

Ex: 
mssql_field_type 
mssql_field_name
mssql_fetch_row

Please check the PHP for MS SQL Server manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)(http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) for the complete list of functions.

---

**UPDATE:**
I had assumed the question to be a question related to SQL Server and accordingly tried to provide a solution for SQL Server. However, as now I have realized that it is a **sqsrv** question, here is the solution.
We can extract the details of field through **sqlsrv_field_metadata** function.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_1";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql );

foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata( $stmt ) as $fieldMetadata ) {
    foreach( $fieldMetadata as $name => $value) {
       echo "$name: $value<br />";
    }
      echo "<br />";
}
```

For other functions and detailed examples, please check the PHP sqlsrv manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php)

Comment: What about sqlsrv ?I am using sqlsrv functions, so will keep to it.

Comment: through sqlsrv_field_metadata you can find field properties like Name, Type, Size etc.

Comment: check the example here  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-field-metadata.php

Comment: @SuvenduShekharGiri I think you should update your answer as it should show `sqlsrv` functions that are equivalent to the `mysql` functions, not `mssql`.